# How to make wider views collapse to new line

Tags: ios, uiview, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewlayout, uistackview

I'm trying to create an iOS view with this behaviour:

- The View contains multiple images and/or labels
- If there are too many view inside it some of them will collapse to a new line
- If the view is small multiple views can be put side to side

The behaviour is similar of the float divs in css, here there is an image to explain better the layout I want to achive

[image]

Currently I'm trying to replicate this layout with a UICollectionView with Flow Layout but I'm firing LOTS of errors. Each cell contains an horizontal stack view which contains the images and labels

Maybe a simpler approach could be to create a custom collection view layout, where each section is a "collapsable row", with the section header, and each cell would be an image or label

Any advice? and in case how can I write such a collection view layout?

Comment: Put your code that you tried

Comment: I think, you can use scroll view. You can prepare custom view for each row and in this view add labels/view.

Comment: I'm using auto layout and storyboards everywhere in the app so I pref not to use programmatic scrollviews :\ if it is the only way I will

Comment: You can use storyboards and add constraints from code (VFL).